# Is there a way to ensure that my azure function app and azure MI database are in the same Availability Zone?

Tags: azure

From azure doc, it says:

> Data transfer between Availability Zones(Egress and Ingress)* £0.009
> per GB Data transfer within same Availability Zone    Free

When I create an azure web app and azure managed instance SQL, I can choose the region (e.g. UK south, West EU etc), but is there a way to make sure that normally my web app and azure database are in the same Availability Zone?

When I create app service plan or Sql on azure portal, seems I can only choose region, not AZ. the DB I need to handle in total is around 2TB, and there are daily updates. So if I can somehow get some app service (the one to update db) in the same region, it could mean some really nice saving.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to guarantee in which availability zone your SQL Managed Instance will run, if the region has 3 AZs, it'll be randomly deployed to one of them. In the November 2022 feature wave, it's been introduced Zone Redundancy for SQLMI, which would be in the context of your requirement.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/zone-redundancy-for-azure-sql-managed-instance-business-critical/ba-p/3677646

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/november-2022-feature-wave-for-azure-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/3677741

Comment: hi, Sorry, I don't really understand how this Zone Redundancy will be good for me? How can that guarantee my webapp and database in the same AZ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Your main requirement is to make your services cheaper, so Zone Redundancy will not help you in that case, it is in preview and it'll available for the Business Critical tier only. I just mentioned it as it's the closest you get to Availability Zone in SQLMI. Like I said in my first sentence, "I'm afraid there is no way to guarantee in which availability zone your SQL Managed Instance will run".